# Dependent filters in Webi report

Tags: filtering, business-objects, webi

I've created a webi report which displays a graph of Total revenue per day, Date is on X axis and Rev is on Y axis.

I've a requirement where the client wants to see it category and sub category wise in the same graph. I've used Filter Bar option and dragged Category. This works fine and displays the revenue for the selected category on a daily basis.

Now I added another filter Sub-Category which should display only the list of sub-categories associated with the Category selected but in turn displays all sub-categories irrespective of the category selected.

Is there a way to link those two filters?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully It might be helpful to someone just in case...

I've created a custom navigation path in my business layer and used it in my webI.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You can create another report sub_report to collect all categories and sub categories
Then you add this sub_report to master report by insert sub_report.